# Laravel cache remember forever

Tags: laravel

I have this piece of code that I thought would remember cache forever:

```php
$setting = \Cache::remember('website_description', 0,  function() {
  return App\Models\Setting::where('name', 'website_description')->first();
});
```

But it doesn't remember at all, someone told me that passing `0` to remember function would make it remember forever. Since this doesn't work what other way can I put an item in cache forever?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just change `remember` to `rememberForever` and remove time parameter

```
 $setting = \Cache::rememberForever('website_description', function() {
            return App\Models\Setting::where('name', 'website_description')->first();
        });
```

[Reference for rememberForever](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Cache/Repository.php#L90)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
if (! \Cache::has('website_description')) {
    \Cache::forever('website_description', App\Models\Setting::where('name', 'website_description')->first());
}
```